# How to enable a tooltip on hover when the button is disabled?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tooltip, antd

I am trying to make the tooltip visible only when I hover over a button when disabled. When the button is enabled, the tooltip should not be seen. I am making use of react and antd.

This is the code I have written,

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Tooltip, Space } from 'antd';
const text = <span>prompt text</span>;
const isEnable = false
const App = () => (
<div>
  <Space>
     <Button>Hi</Button>
     <Tooltip placement="bottom" title={text} trigger={'hover'} visible={!isEnable}>
       <span>
         <Button disabled={!isEnable} >
           <Space>
             <span>Hello</span>
           </Space>
         </Button>
       </span>
      </Tooltip>
  </Space>
</div>
);
export default App;
```

isEnable is a variable which is keeping track when the button becomes enabled and disabled. Here, I am able to hide the tooltip when the button is enabled. When the button is disabled, I tried triggering hover to make the tooltip visible on hover, but that is not working. Is there a way to make the tooltip visible on hover and disappear soon after the mouse moves away from the button?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

To enable a tooltip on hover even when the button is disabled, you can add the title attribute to the button with the tooltip text and set the CSS property pointer-events to auto.

Here's an example:

HTML:

```
<button disabled title="Tooltip Text">Disabled Button</button>
```

```
button[disabled] {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Or use this sx props.